# Use for loop to fill empty values of a dataframe based on matching with other dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I have this nearly empty dataframe

```
new_df<-structure(list(id = c("R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
"R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
"R_88j7lG37gLfxk22"), choice = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), low_env = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mid_env = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), high_env = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), low_eth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mid_eth = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), high_eth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `low_pri($25)` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `mid_pri($75)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), `high_pri($125)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

which i want to fill in order to be like

[image]

I use the data and the method below which works for the first 3 rows but not for the next 3(leave out choice its working)

```
    long1<-structure(list(id = "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", t1_choice = "2", t2_choice = "1", 
    t3_choice = "1", t4_choice = "2", t1_p1_env = "high_env", 
    t1_p1_eth = "low_eth", t1_p1_pri = "$125", t1_p2_env = "mid_env", 
    t1_p2_eth = "high_eth", t1_p2_pri = "$25", t1_p3_env = "low_env", 
    t1_p3_eth = "mid_eth", t1_p3_pri = "$75", t2_p1_env = "high_env", 
    t2_p1_eth = "low_eth", t2_p1_pri = "$75", t2_p2_env = "mid_env", 
    t2_p2_eth = "mid_eth", t2_p2_pri = "$125", t2_p3_env = "mid_env", 
    t2_p3_eth = "mid_eth", t2_p3_pri = "$75", t3_p1_env = "high_env", 
    t3_p1_eth = "high_eth", t3_p1_pri = "$125", t3_p2_env = "mid_env", 
    t3_p2_eth = "low_eth", t3_p2_pri = "$25", t3_p3_env = "low_env", 
    t3_p3_eth = "high_eth", t3_p3_pri = "$25", t4_p1_env = "low_env", 
    t4_p1_eth = "low_eth", t4_p1_pri = "$75", t4_p2_env = "high_env", 
    t4_p2_eth = "mid_eth", t4_p2_pri = "$125", t4_p3_env = "low_env", 
    t4_p3_eth = "high_eth", t4_p3_pri = "$25"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#working
# Loop through the first three rows of new_df
for (i in 1:3) {
  # Extracting the required values from long1 for each row
  env <- long1[paste0("t1_p", i, "_env")][1]
  eth <- long1[paste0("t1_p", i, "_eth")][1]
  pri <- long1[paste0("t1_p", i, "_pri")][1]
 
   # Matching values from long1 to new_df columns in the corresponding row
   new_df[i, "low_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "low_env")
   new_df[i, "mid_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "mid_env")
   new_df[i, "high_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "high_env")
   new_df[i, "low_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "low_eth")
   new_df[i, "mid_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "mid_eth")
   new_df[i, "high_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "high_eth")
   new_df[i, "low_pri($25)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$25")
   new_df[i, "mid_pri($75)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$75")
   new_df[i, "high_pri($125)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$125")
 
}
#not working
# Loop through the second three rows of new_df
for (i in 1:3) {
  # Extracting the required values from long1 for each row
  env <- long1[paste0("t2_p", i, "_env")][1]
  eth <- long1[paste0("t2_p", i, "_eth")][1]
  pri <- long1[paste0("t2_p", i, "_pri")][1]
  for(j in 4:6){
    # Matching values from long1 to new_df columns in the corresponding row
    new_df[j, "low_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "low_env")
    new_df[j, "mid_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "mid_env")
    new_df[j, "high_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "high_env")
    new_df[j, "low_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "low_eth")
    new_df[j, "mid_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "mid_eth")
    new_df[j, "high_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "high_eth")
    new_df[j, "low_pri($25)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$25")
    new_df[j, "mid_pri($75)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$75")
    new_df[j, "high_pri($125)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$125")
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create new_df
new_df <- structure(list(id = c("R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
                                "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
                                "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22"), choice = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), low_env = c(NA, 
                                                                                                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mid_env = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), high_env = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), low_eth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mid_eth = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), high_eth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `low_pri($25)` = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `mid_pri($75)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ), `high_pri($125)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           6L), class = "data.frame")

# Create long1
long1 <- structure(list(id = "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", t1_choice = "2", t2_choice = "1", 
                        t3_choice = "1", t4_choice = "2", t1_p1_env = "high_env", 
                        t1_p1_eth = "low_eth", t1_p1_pri = "$125", t1_p2_env = "mid_env", 
                        t1_p2_eth = "high_eth", t1_p2_pri = "$25", t1_p3_env = "low_env", 
                        t1_p3_eth = "mid_eth", t1_p3_pri = "$75", t2_p1_env = "high_env", 
                        t2_p1_eth = "low_eth", t2_p1_pri = "$75", t2_p2_env = "mid_env", 
                        t2_p2_eth = "mid_eth", t2_p2_pri = "$125", t2_p3_env = "mid_env", 
                        t2_p3_eth = "mid_eth", t2_p3_pri = "$75", t3_p1_env = "high_env", 
                        t3_p1_eth = "high_eth", t3_p1_pri = "$125", t3_p2_env = "mid_env", 
                        t3_p2_eth = "low_eth", t3_p2_pri = "$25", t3_p3_env = "low_env", 
                        t3_p3_eth = "high_eth", t3_p3_pri = "$25", t4_p1_env = "low_env", 
                        t4_p1_eth = "low_eth", t4_p1_pri = "$75", t4_p2_env = "high_env", 
                        t4_p2_eth = "mid_eth", t4_p2_pri = "$125", t4_p3_env = "low_env", 
                        t4_p3_eth = "high_eth", t4_p3_pri = "$25"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                  -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Loop through the first three rows of new_df
for (i in 1:3) {
  # Extracting the required values from long1 for each row
  env <- long1[paste0("t1_p", i, "_env")][1]
  eth <- long1[paste0("t1_p", i, "_eth")][1]
  pri <- long1[paste0("t1_p", i, "_pri")][1]
  
  # Matching values from long1 to new_df columns in the corresponding row
  new_df[i, "low_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "low_env")
  new_df[i, "mid_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "mid_env")
  new_df[i, "high_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "high_env")
  new_df[i, "low_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "low_eth")
  new_df[i, "mid_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "mid_eth")
  new_df[i, "high_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "high_eth")
  new_df[i, "low_pri($25)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$25")
  new_df[i, "mid_pri($75)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$75")
  new_df[i, "high_pri($125)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$125")
}

# Loop through the second three rows of new_df
for (i in 1:3) {
  # Extracting the required values from long1 for each row
  env <- long1[paste0("t2_p", i, "_env")][1]
  eth <- long1[paste0("t2_p", i, "_eth")][1]
  pri <- long1[paste0("t2_p", i, "_pri")][1]
  
  # Matching values from long1 to new_df columns in the corresponding row
  new_df[i + 3, "low_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "low_env")
  new_df[i + 3, "mid_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "mid_env")
  new_df[i + 3, "high_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "high_env")
  new_df[i + 3, "low_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "low_eth")
  new_df[i + 3, "mid_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "mid_eth")
  new_df[i + 3, "high_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "high_eth")
  new_df[i + 3, "low_pri($25)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$25")
  new_df[i + 3, "mid_pri($75)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$75")
  new_df[i + 3, "high_pri($125)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$125")
  
  # Adjusting the choice column
  new_df[i + 3, "choice"] <- as.numeric(long1[paste0("t2_choice")][1] == i)
}


new_df
                 id choice low_env mid_env high_env low_eth mid_eth high_eth low_pri($25) mid_pri($75)
1 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22      0       0       0        1       1       0        0            0            0
2 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22      1       0       1        0       0       0        1            1            0
3 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22      0       1       0        0       0       1        0            0            1
4 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22      1       0       0        1       1       0        0            0            1
5 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22      0       0       1        0       0       1        0            0            0
6 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22      0       0       1        0       0       1        0            0            1
  high_pri($125)
1              1
2              0
3              0
4              0
5              1
6              0
```

Comment: Kindly see the updated code, small mistake is there I edited as column choice was not matched

Comment: choice needed no change. should I use the edited though?

Comment: Ya, This updated code, will give properly,

Comment: pRevious code was little issue with choice colum, that I resolved in updated code, I hope

Comment: if i want to find for +6 and +9 how shou;d I adjust choice?

Comment: this question is based on your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77773544/apply-data-process-to-all-rows-of-dataset-using-a-for-loop