# Apply data process to all rows of dataset using a for() loop

Tags: r

I have this empty dataframe

```
new_df<-structure(list(id = c("R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
"R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
"R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
"R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
"R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", 
"R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", 
"R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", 
"R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", 
"R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4"), choice = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), low_env = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mid_env = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), high_env = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), low_eth = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mid_eth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), high_eth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `low_pri($25)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `mid_pri($75)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `high_pri($125)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    )), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

and with the data and code above I fill half of it based on the first row of the `long` dataset. How can I use a `for()` loop in order to apply this method to the rest of the rows of the `long` dataset which will fill the other half?

```
long<-structure(list(id = c("R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4"
), t1_choice = c("2", "3"), t2_choice = c("1", "3"), t3_choice = c("1", 
"2"), t4_choice = c("2", "1"), t1_p1_env = c("high_env", "mid_env"
), t1_p1_eth = c("low_eth", "mid_eth"), t1_p1_pri = c("$125", 
"$25"), t1_p2_env = c("mid_env", "high_env"), t1_p2_eth = c("high_eth", 
"low_eth"), t1_p2_pri = c("$25", "$75"), t1_p3_env = c("low_env", 
"low_env"), t1_p3_eth = c("mid_eth", "low_eth"), t1_p3_pri = c("$75", 
"$75"), t2_p1_env = c("high_env", "mid_env"), t2_p1_eth = c("low_eth", 
"high_eth"), t2_p1_pri = c("$75", "$125"), t2_p2_env = c("mid_env", 
"low_env"), t2_p2_eth = c("mid_eth", "low_eth"), t2_p2_pri = c("$125", 
"$75"), t2_p3_env = c("mid_env", "high_env"), t2_p3_eth = c("mid_eth", 
"high_eth"), t2_p3_pri = c("$75", "$75"), t3_p1_env = c("high_env", 
"mid_env"), t3_p1_eth = c("high_eth", "mid_eth"), t3_p1_pri = c("$125", 
"$125"), t3_p2_env = c("mid_env", "high_env"), t3_p2_eth = c("low_eth", 
"low_eth"), t3_p2_pri = c("$25", "$25"), t3_p3_env = c("low_env", 
"low_env"), t3_p3_eth = c("high_eth", "high_eth"), t3_p3_pri = c("$25", 
"$75"), t4_p1_env = c("low_env", "high_env"), t4_p1_eth = c("low_eth", 
"low_eth"), t4_p1_pri = c("$75", "$125"), t4_p2_env = c("high_env", 
"mid_env"), t4_p2_eth = c("mid_eth", "mid_eth"), t4_p2_pri = c("$125", 
"$25"), t4_p3_env = c("low_env", "low_env"), t4_p3_eth = c("high_eth", 
"mid_eth"), t4_p3_pri = c("$25", "$125")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#working
# Loop through the first three rows of new_df
for (i in 1:3) {
  # Extracting the required values from long1 for each row
  env <- long[1,][paste0("t1_p", i, "_env")][1]
  eth <- long[1,][paste0("t1_p", i, "_eth")][1]
  pri <- long[1,][paste0("t1_p", i, "_pri")][1]
  
  # Matching values from long[1,] to new_df columns in the corresponding row
  new_df[i, "low_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "low_env")
  new_df[i, "mid_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "mid_env")
  new_df[i, "high_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "high_env")
  new_df[i, "low_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "low_eth")
  new_df[i, "mid_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "mid_eth")
  new_df[i, "high_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "high_eth")
  new_df[i, "low_pri($25)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$25")
  new_df[i, "mid_pri($75)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$75")
  new_df[i, "high_pri($125)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$125")
}

# Loop through the second three rows of new_df
for (i in 1:3) {
  # Extracting the required values from long[1,] for each row
  env <- long[1,][paste0("t2_p", i, "_env")][1]
  eth <- long[1,][paste0("t2_p", i, "_eth")][1]
  pri <- long[1,][paste0("t2_p", i, "_pri")][1]
  
  # Matching values from long[1,] to new_df columns in the corresponding row
  new_df[i + 3, "low_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "low_env")
  new_df[i + 3, "mid_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "mid_env")
  new_df[i + 3, "high_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "high_env")
  new_df[i + 3, "low_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "low_eth")
  new_df[i + 3, "mid_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "mid_eth")
  new_df[i + 3, "high_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "high_eth")
  new_df[i + 3, "low_pri($25)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$25")
  new_df[i + 3, "mid_pri($75)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$75")
  new_df[i + 3, "high_pri($125)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$125")
  # Adjusting the choice column
  new_df[i + 3, "choice"] <- as.numeric(long[1,][paste0("t2_choice")][1] == i)
}
  # Loop through the second three rows of new_df
  for (i in 1:3) {
    # Extracting the required values from long[1,] for each row
    env <- long[1,][paste0("t3_p", i, "_env")][1]
    eth <- long[1,][paste0("t3_p", i, "_eth")][1]
    pri <- long[1,][paste0("t3_p", i, "_pri")][1]
    
    # Matching values from long[1,] to new_df columns in the corresponding row
    new_df[i + 6, "low_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "low_env")
    new_df[i + 6, "mid_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "mid_env")
    new_df[i + 6, "high_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "high_env")
    new_df[i + 6, "low_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "low_eth")
    new_df[i + 6, "mid_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "mid_eth")
    new_df[i + 6, "high_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "high_eth")
    new_df[i + 6, "low_pri($25)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$25")
    new_df[i + 6, "mid_pri($75)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$75")
    new_df[i + 6, "high_pri($125)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$125")
    # Adjusting the choice column
    new_df[i + 6, "choice"] <- as.numeric(long[1,][paste0("t3_choice")][1] == i)
  }
for (i in 1:3) {
  # Extracting the required values from long[1,] for each row
  env <- long[1,][paste0("t4_p", i, "_env")][1]
  eth <- long[1,][paste0("t4_p", i, "_eth")][1]
  pri <- long[1,][paste0("t4_p", i, "_pri")][1]
  
  # Matching values from long[1,] to new_df columns in the corresponding row
  new_df[i + 9, "low_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "low_env")
  new_df[i + 9, "mid_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "mid_env")
  new_df[i + 9, "high_env"] <- as.numeric(env == "high_env")
  new_df[i + 9, "low_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "low_eth")
  new_df[i + 9, "mid_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "mid_eth")
  new_df[i + 9, "high_eth"] <- as.numeric(eth == "high_eth")
  new_df[i + 9, "low_pri($25)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$25")
  new_df[i + 9, "mid_pri($75)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$75")
  new_df[i + 9, "high_pri($125)"] <- as.numeric(pri == "$125")
  

  # Adjusting the choice column
  new_df[i + 9, "choice"] <- as.numeric(long[1,][paste0("t4_choice")][1] == i)
}
```

expected result

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach doesn't look fun at the moment. Instead you could assign more favorable `names` (i.e. times as a suffix instead of the strange prefix format) then `reshape` the data two times to desired long format and use `model.matrix` to get one-hot coding. Not sure how you got the choice variable since you've hard-coded it, but you will know it. To get all levels we need to `type.convert(as.is=FALSE)` to get `factor`s then set `contrasts` to `FALSE`.

```
> names(long)[-1] <- 
+   strsplit(names(long)[-1], '_') |>
+   sapply(\(x) paste(paste(c(rev(x[-1])), collapse='_'), x[1], sep='.'))
> res <- reshape(as.data.frame(long), varying=-1, direction='l') |>
+   reshape(direction='l', varying=-(1:3), new.row.names=1:1e9, sep='_') |>
+   type.convert(as.is=FALSE)
> cbind(res[1:3], model.matrix(~ 0 + env + eth + pri, res, 
+                              contrasts.arg = list(eth=contrasts(res$eth, contrasts=FALSE),
+                                                   pri=contrasts(res$pri, contrasts=FALSE))))
                  id time choice envhigh_env envlow_env envmid_env ethhigh_eth ethlow_eth ethmid_eth pri$125 pri$25 pri$75
1  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      2           1          0          0           0          1          0       1      0      0
2  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      3           0          0          1           0          0          1       0      1      0
3  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      1           1          0          0           0          1          0       0      0      1
4  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      3           0          0          1           1          0          0       1      0      0
5  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      1           1          0          0           1          0          0       1      0      0
6  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      2           0          0          1           0          0          1       1      0      0
7  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      2           0          1          0           0          1          0       0      0      1
8  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      1           1          0          0           0          1          0       1      0      0
9  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      2           0          0          1           1          0          0       0      1      0
10 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      3           1          0          0           0          1          0       0      0      1
11 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      1           0          0          1           0          0          1       1      0      0
12 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      3           0          1          0           0          1          0       0      0      1
13 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      1           0          0          1           0          1          0       0      1      0
14 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      2           1          0          0           0          1          0       0      1      0
15 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      2           1          0          0           0          0          1       1      0      0
16 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      1           0          0          1           0          0          1       0      1      0
17 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      2           0          1          0           0          0          1       0      0      1
18 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      3           0          1          0           0          1          0       0      0      1
19 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      1           0          0          1           0          0          1       0      0      1
20 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      3           1          0          0           1          0          0       0      0      1
21 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      1           0          1          0           1          0          0       0      1      0
22 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      2           0          1          0           1          0          0       0      0      1
23 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      2           0          1          0           1          0          0       0      1      0
24 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      1           0          1          0           0          0          1       1      0      0
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(long)
structure(list(id = c("R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4"
), t1_choice = c("2", "3"), t2_choice = c("1", "3"), t3_choice = c("1", 
"2"), t4_choice = c("2", "1"), t1_p1_env = c("high_env", "mid_env"
), t1_p1_eth = c("low_eth", "mid_eth"), t1_p1_pri = c("$125", 
"$25"), t1_p2_env = c("mid_env", "high_env"), t1_p2_eth = c("high_eth", 
"low_eth"), t1_p2_pri = c("$25", "$75"), t1_p3_env = c("low_env", 
"low_env"), t1_p3_eth = c("mid_eth", "low_eth"), t1_p3_pri = c("$75", 
"$75"), t2_p1_env = c("high_env", "mid_env"), t2_p1_eth = c("low_eth", 
"high_eth"), t2_p1_pri = c("$75", "$125"), t2_p2_env = c("mid_env", 
"low_env"), t2_p2_eth = c("mid_eth", "low_eth"), t2_p2_pri = c("$125", 
"$75"), t2_p3_env = c("mid_env", "high_env"), t2_p3_eth = c("mid_eth", 
"high_eth"), t2_p3_pri = c("$75", "$75"), t3_p1_env = c("high_env", 
"mid_env"), t3_p1_eth = c("high_eth", "mid_eth"), t3_p1_pri = c("$125", 
"$125"), t3_p2_env = c("mid_env", "high_env"), t3_p2_eth = c("low_eth", 
"low_eth"), t3_p2_pri = c("$25", "$25"), t3_p3_env = c("low_env", 
"low_env"), t3_p3_eth = c("high_eth", "high_eth"), t3_p3_pri = c("$25", 
"$75"), t4_p1_env = c("low_env", "high_env"), t4_p1_eth = c("low_eth", 
"low_eth"), t4_p1_pri = c("$75", "$125"), t4_p2_env = c("high_env", 
"mid_env"), t4_p2_eth = c("mid_eth", "mid_eth"), t4_p2_pri = c("$125", 
"$25"), t4_p3_env = c("low_env", "low_env"), t4_p3_eth = c("high_eth", 
"mid_eth"), t4_p3_pri = c("$25", "$125")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: i cant see pri$125 everything works except from this also high_eth is missing. expected result is like the image i attached

Comment: @firmo23 The solution is to set `contrasts` to `FALSE`, see edit. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62116776/6574038).

Comment: the choice column needed a separate calculation so I created a new q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77778180/convert-data-from-wide-to-long-format-by-checking-that-criteria-met-in-columns

Comment: @firmo23 As said, I'm afraid I don't understand the logic you creating _choice_. BTW why still using *t1_choice* instead of *choice_t1*?

Answer (score 1):

```
I think here is the answer
new_df<-structure(list(id = c("R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
                              "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
                              "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
                              "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", 
                              "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", 
                              "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", 
                              "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", 
                              "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", 
                              "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4"), choice = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                                                               1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), low_env = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mid_env = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                           NA, NA), high_env = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), low_eth = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mid_eth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, NA, NA), high_eth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                       `low_pri($25)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                       `mid_pri($75)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                       `high_pri($125)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
                       )), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = "data.frame")


long<-structure(list(id = c("R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4"
), t1_choice = c("2", "3"), t2_choice = c("1", "3"), t3_choice = c("1", 
                                                                   "2"), t4_choice = c("2", "1"), t1_p1_env = c("high_env", "mid_env"
                                                                   ), t1_p1_eth = c("low_eth", "mid_eth"), t1_p1_pri = c("$125", 
                                                                                                                         "$25"), t1_p2_env = c("mid_env", "high_env"), t1_p2_eth = c("high_eth", 
                                                                                                                                                                                     "low_eth"), t1_p2_pri = c("$25", "$75"), t1_p3_env = c("low_env", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "low_env"), t1_p3_eth = c("mid_eth", "low_eth"), t1_p3_pri = c("$75", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "$75"), t2_p1_env = c("high_env", "mid_env"), t2_p1_eth = c("low_eth", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "high_eth"), t2_p1_pri = c("$75", "$125"), t2_p2_env = c("mid_env", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "low_env"), t2_p2_eth = c("mid_eth", "low_eth"), t2_p2_pri = c("$125", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "$75"), t2_p3_env = c("mid_env", "high_env"), t2_p3_eth = c("mid_eth", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "high_eth"), t2_p3_pri = c("$75", "$75"), t3_p1_env = c("high_env", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "mid_env"), t3_p1_eth = c("high_eth", "mid_eth"), t3_p1_pri = c("$125", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "$125"), t3_p2_env = c("mid_env", "high_env"), t3_p2_eth = c("low_eth", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "low_eth"), t3_p2_pri = c("$25", "$25"), t3_p3_env = c("low_env", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "low_env"), t3_p3_eth = c("high_eth", "high_eth"), t3_p3_pri = c("$25", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "$75"), t4_p1_env = c("low_env", "high_env"), t4_p1_eth = c("low_eth", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "low_eth"), t4_p1_pri = c("$75", "$125"), t4_p2_env = c("high_env", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "mid_env"), t4_p2_eth = c("mid_eth", "mid_eth"), t4_p2_pri = c("$125", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "$25"), t4_p3_env = c("low_env", "low_env"), t4_p3_eth = c("high_eth", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "mid_eth"), t4_p3_pri = c("$25", "$125")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



library(dplyr)

# Modify column names in long
names(long)[-1] <- strsplit(names(long)[-1], '_') %>%
  sapply(function(x) paste(paste(c(rev(x[-1])), collapse='_'), x[1], sep='.'))

# Reshape long dataset
res <- long %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  reshape(varying=-1, direction='long') %>%
  reshape(direction='long', varying=-(1:3), new.row.names=1:1e9, sep='_')

# Manually create dummy variables for env, eth, and pri
env_dummy <- model.matrix(~ 0 + env, res, contrasts = FALSE)
eth_dummy <- model.matrix(~ 0 + eth, res, contrasts = FALSE)
pri_dummy <- model.matrix(~ 0 + pri, res, contrasts = FALSE)

# Combine the original columns with the dummy variables
model_matrix <- cbind(res[1:3], env_dummy, eth_dummy, pri_dummy)

# Display the result
print(model_matrix)

print(model_matrix)
                  id time choice envhigh_env envlow_env envmid_env ethhigh_eth ethlow_eth ethmid_eth pri$125
1  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      2           1          0          0           0          1          0       1
2  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      3           0          0          1           0          0          1       0
3  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      1           1          0          0           0          1          0       0
4  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      3           0          0          1           1          0          0       1
5  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      1           1          0          0           1          0          0       1
6  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      2           0          0          1           0          0          1       1
7  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      2           0          1          0           0          1          0       0
8  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      1           1          0          0           0          1          0       1
9  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      2           0          0          1           1          0          0       0
10 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      3           1          0          0           0          1          0       0
11 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      1           0          0          1           0          0          1       1
12 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      3           0          1          0           0          1          0       0
13 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      1           0          0          1           0          1          0       0
14 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      2           1          0          0           0          1          0       0
15 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      2           1          0          0           0          0          1       1
16 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      1           0          0          1           0          0          1       0
17 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      2           0          1          0           0          0          1       0
18 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      3           0          1          0           0          1          0       0
19 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      1           0          0          1           0          0          1       0
20 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      3           1          0          0           1          0          0       0
21 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      1           0          1          0           1          0          0       0
22 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      2           0          1          0           1          0          0       0
23 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      2           0          1          0           1          0          0       0
24 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      1           0          1          0           0          0          1       1
   pri$25 pri$75
1       0      0
2       1      0
3       0      1
4       0      0
5       0      0
6       0      0
7       0      1
8       0      0
9       1      0
10      0      1
11      0      0
12      0      1
13      1      0
14      1      0
15      0      0
16      1      0
17      0      1
18      0      1
19      0      1
20      0      1
21      1      0
22      0      1
23      1      0
24      0      0
```

Comment: the choice column needed a separate calculation so I created a new q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77778180/convert-data-from-wide-to-long-format-by-checking-that-criteria-met-in-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

# Modify column names in long
names(long)[-1] <- strsplit(names(long)[-1], '_') %>%
  sapply(function(x) paste(paste(c(rev(x[-1])), collapse='_'), x[1], sep='.'))

# Reshape long dataset
res <- long %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  reshape(varying=-1, direction='long') %>%
  reshape(direction='long', varying=-(1:3), new.row.names=1:1e9, sep='_')

# Create a model matrix
model_matrix <- cbind(res[1:3], model.matrix(~ 0 + env + eth + pri, res))

# Display the result
print(model_matrix)

id time choice envhigh_env envlow_env envmid_env ethlow_eth ethmid_eth pri$25 pri$75
1  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      2           1          0          0          1          0      0      0
2  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      3           0          0          1          0          1      1      0
3  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      1           1          0          0          1          0      0      1
4  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      3           0          0          1          0          0      0      0
5  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      1           1          0          0          0          0      0      0
6  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      2           0          0          1          0          1      0      0
7  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p1      2           0          1          0          1          0      0      1
8  R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p1      1           1          0          0          1          0      0      0
9  R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      2           0          0          1          0          0      1      0
10 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      3           1          0          0          1          0      0      1
11 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      1           0          0          1          0          1      0      0
12 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      3           0          1          0          1          0      0      1
13 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      1           0          0          1          1          0      1      0
14 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      2           1          0          0          1          0      1      0
15 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p2      2           1          0          0          0          1      0      0
16 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p2      1           0          0          1          0          1      1      0
17 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      2           0          1          0          0          1      0      1
18 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      3           0          1          0          1          0      0      1
19 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      1           0          0          1          0          1      0      1
20 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      3           1          0          0          0          0      0      1
21 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      1           0          1          0          0          0      1      0
22 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      2           0          1          0          0          0      0      1
23 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22   p3      2           0          1          0          0          0      1      0
24 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4   p3      1           0          1          0          0          1      0      0
```

hi, but if i run this

```
library(dplyr)

# Modify column names in long
names(long)[-1] <- strsplit(names(long)[-1], '_') %>%
  sapply(function(x) paste(paste(c(rev(x[-1])), collapse='_'), x[1], sep='.'))

# Reshape long dataset
res <- long %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  reshape(varying=-1, direction='long') %>%
  reshape(direction='long', varying=-(1:3), new.row.names=1:100, sep='_')

# Ensure all combinations of env, eth, and pri are present
all_combinations <- expand.grid(env = unique(res$env), eth = unique(res$eth), pri = c("$25", "$75", "$125"))

# Merge with res to fill missing combinations with NA
res <- merge(all_combinations, res, all = TRUE)

# Convert 'pri' to factor with appropriate levels
res$pri <- factor(res$pri, levels = c("$25", "$75", "$125"))
res$eth <- factor(res$pri, levels = c("$25", "$75", "$125"))

# Create a model matrix manually including dummy variables for pri
model_matrix <- cbind(res[1:3], model.matrix(~ 0 + env + eth + pri - 1, res))

# Display the result
print(model_matrix)
View(model_matrix)
env      eth  pri envhigh_env envmid_env envlow_env ethmid_eth ethhigh_eth pri$75 pri$125
1  high_env  low_eth  $25           1          0          0          0           0      0       0
2  high_env  low_eth  $75           1          0          0          0           0      1       0
3  high_env  low_eth  $75           1          0          0          0           0      1       0
4  high_env  low_eth $125           1          0          0          0           0      0       1
5  high_env  low_eth $125           1          0          0          0           0      0       1
6  high_env  mid_eth  $25           1          0          0          1           0      0       0
7  high_env  mid_eth  $75           1          0          0          1           0      1       0
8  high_env  mid_eth $125           1          0          0          1           0      0       1
9  high_env high_eth  $25           1          0          0          0           1      0       0
10 high_env high_eth  $75           1          0          0          0           1      1       0
11 high_env high_eth $125           1          0          0          0           1      0       1
12  mid_env  low_eth  $25           0          1          0          0           0      0       0
13  mid_env  low_eth  $75           0          1          0          0           0      1       0
14  mid_env  low_eth $125           0          1          0          0           0      0       1
15  mid_env  mid_eth  $25           0          1          0          1           0      0       0
16  mid_env  mid_eth  $25           0          1          0          1           0      0       0
17  mid_env  mid_eth  $75           0          1          0          1           0      1       0
18  mid_env  mid_eth $125           0          1          0          1           0      0       1
19  mid_env  mid_eth $125           0          1          0          1           0      0       1
20  mid_env high_eth  $25           0          1          0          0           1      0       0
21  mid_env high_eth  $75           0          1          0          0           1      1       0
22  mid_env high_eth $125           0          1          0          0           1      0       1
23  low_env  low_eth  $25           0          0          1          0           0      0       0
24  low_env  low_eth  $75           0          0          1          0           0      1       0
25  low_env  low_eth  $75           0          0          1          0           0      1       0
26  low_env  low_eth  $75           0          0          1          0           0      1       0
27  low_env  low_eth $125           0          0          1          0           0      0       1
28  low_env  mid_eth  $25           0          0          1          1           0      0       0
29  low_env  mid_eth  $75           0          0          1          1           0      1       0
30  low_env  mid_eth $125           0          0          1          1           0      0       1
31  low_env high_eth  $25           0          0          1          0           1      0       0
32  low_env high_eth  $25           0          0          1          0           1      0       0
33  low_env high_eth  $75           0          0          1          0           1      1       0
34  low_env high_eth $125           0          0          1          0           1      0       1
```

other two query is answered, but still missing, I think it wont able to covel all level, u can see in one case its coming 24 row, and in this case its coming 34 row but I am not able to rectify further

Comment: i cant see pri$125 everything works except from this also high_eth is missing. expected result is like the image i attached

Comment: the choice column needed a separate calculation so I created a new q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77778180/convert-data-from-wide-to-long-format-by-checking-that-criteria-met-in-columns