# Convert data from wide to long format by checking the values of a row

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have the data below

```
data<-structure(list(id = c("R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4"
), t1_choice = c("2", "3"), t2_choice = c("1", "3"), t3_choice = c("1", 
"2"), t4_choice = c("2", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

this is the first row my data:

[image]

and I want to convert it to a long format like below with this logic.For every participant there are 12 rows, because there are 4 tasks (4 't's) and 3 profiles in each task (3 'p's). The choice column is a binary where it is 1 if the profile in that row was chosen in that task and 0 if it was not, which is information contained in the 'tN_choice' columns.

[image]

my method is wrong

```
tasks<-4
profiles<-3
#column position of first task
cpft<-2

#column position of last task
cplt<-5

# Extracting choices
choices <- as.numeric(unlist(long[, cpft:cplt]))

# Create the new dataframe with id and choice columns
new_df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(data$id, each = tasks*profiles),
  choice = rep(0, times = length(id))
)

# Replacing values based on original choices
for (i in 1:(tasks*profiles)) {
  idx <- (i - 1) * profiles + choices[i]
  new_df$choice[idx] <- 1
}
```

Comment: I voted to re-open, yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format post helps with 1st step reshaping wide-to-long, but doesn't address the 2nd step - convert to binary.

Comment: What does `3 'p's` mean? I understand that there are 4 tasks, but how would we derive that there are 3 profiles?

Comment: cause the choices are 1,2,3 in the tasks

Comment: Well the choices are `1` and `2` in your example.

Comment: yes in those rows but there are more I just put the minimal data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can try this

```
data %>%
    pivot_longer(-id) %>%
    summarise(choice = list(+(seq(3) == value)), .by = c(id, name)) %>%
    unnest(choice) %>%
    print(n = 1000000L) # just to print more rows
```

which gives

```
   id                name      choice
   <chr>             <chr>      <int>
 1 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t1_choice      0
 2 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t1_choice      1
 3 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t1_choice      0
 4 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t2_choice      1
 5 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t2_choice      0
 6 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t2_choice      0
 7 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t3_choice      1
 8 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t3_choice      0
 9 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t3_choice      0
10 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t4_choice      0
11 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t4_choice      1
12 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 t4_choice      0
13 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t1_choice      0
14 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t1_choice      0
15 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t1_choice      1
16 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t2_choice      0
17 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t2_choice      0
18 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t2_choice      1
19 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t3_choice      0
20 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t3_choice      1
21 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t3_choice      0
22 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t4_choice      1
23 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t4_choice      0
24 R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4 t4_choice      0
```

Comment: As you are using unary `+` instead of the longer but IMHO more verbose `as.integer` and I never understand what unary plus is doing you may be the right person to enlighten me about ist use, am I right to deduct that unary plus is a no-op for numbers and a cast for logicals or is there any other effect of the unary plus I am not aware of?

Comment: @thothal Note that `+TRUE == 0L+TRUE`. According to the hierarchy logical < factor < integer < numeric < character, "integer" is higher than "logical" so the latter will be coerced to the former.

Comment: Understood, so is my assumption valid? unary `+`  does a type cast from logical to integer, but is otherwise a no-op for numbers?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding it works but only for 1 row of data. I added a second row in my dataset and it gives only zeros for the data of the second row. I just put minimal data here. There are many rows in my actual. The possible choices in 4 tasks are 1,2,3

Comment: @thothal That's correct, `+1 != as.integer(1)`, `+` only works for logical. However, `as.integer` calls [`do_asatomic`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/67cf395ba588bd2e80ec01c6c19a099519654747/src/main/coerce.c#L1458) under the hood and, thus, also does type casting (termed _coercion_ in R).

Comment: @thothal I think you are right that it is type casting. and also, when you type ``` ?`+` ```, you will see a statement: *Unary + and unary - return a numeric or complex vector. All attributes (including class) are preserved if there is no coercion: logical x is coerced to integer and names, dims and dimnames are preserved.*.

Comment: @firmo23 I don't see the all zeros for the second row. Plz see my update

Comment: @jay.sf ahhh, `as.integer` drops names, while unary `+` preserves them. I did read the help, but this subtlety evaded my attention ;)