# Scan a row of data and create a new long dataset with a column with binary values based on the values of this row

Tags: r

This is my initial data

```
long5<-structure(list(id = c("R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", "R_6DK8lERVf8lSQf4", 
"R_eG8g4wMm8JsqNlI", "R_9TCgsW0sLA4xHOm", "R_6J5Obu2AvpCeu9w"
), .choice.t1 = c("2", "3", "3", "2", "1"), .choice.t2 = c("1", 
"3", "1", "3", "1"), .choice.t3 = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "3"), 
    .choice.t4 = c("2", "1", "3", "2", "1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

its first row is like:

[image]

and I want to convert it to:

[image]

as you can see for every id I check t1 to t4 choices which are from 1 to 3 and then create a new column named `choice` which has 1 in the **second** row per color for example if the choice is **2**, 1 in the **first** row per color if the choice is **1** and 1 in the **3rd** row per color if the choice is **3**. My actual dataset haw more rows

I try with this but it does not work:

```
names(long5)[-1] <- 
  strsplit(names(long5)[-1], '_') |>
  sapply(\(x) paste(paste(c(rev(x[-1])), collapse='_'), x[1], sep='.'))
res <- reshape(as.data.frame(long5), varying=-1, direction='l') |>
  reshape(direction='l', varying=-(1:3), new.row.names=1:1e9, sep='_') |>
  type.convert(as.is=FALSE)
all<-cbind(res[1:3], model.matrix(~ 0 + env + eth + pri, res, 
                                  contrasts.arg = list(eth=contrasts(res$eth, contrasts=FALSE),
                                                       pri=contrasts(res$pri, contrasts=FALSE))))
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77773544/20002111

Comment: related but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest keeping the `.choice.t#` name available, and adding the sequence within each `c(id, name)` grouping, so that if your data is ever re-arranged, it will be unambiguous.

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
pivot_longer(long5, cols = -id) %>%
  reframe(choices = 1:3, choice = +(choices == value), .by = c("id", "name"))
# # A tibble: 60 × 4
#    id                name       choices choice
#    <chr>             <chr>        <int>  <int>
#  1 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t1       1      0
#  2 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t1       2      1
#  3 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t1       3      0
#  4 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t2       1      1
#  5 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t2       2      0
#  6 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t2       3      0
#  7 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t3       1      1
#  8 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t3       2      0
#  9 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t3       3      0
# 10 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 .choice.t4       1      0
# # ℹ 50 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

## base R + reshape2

```r
reshape2::melt(long5, id.vars = "id") |>
  merge(data.frame(choices = 1:3), by = c()) |>
  transform(choice = +(choices == value))
```

(Different order of rows, but otherwise equivalent output.)

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define dummy data
df<-structure(list(id = "R_88j7lG37gLfxk22", t1_choice = "2", t2_choice = "1", 
                     t3_choice = "1", t4_choice = "2"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"))

# reshape longer
df_long <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(
    !id,
    names_to = "task",
    names_pattern = "t(\\d+).*",
    values_to = "choice"
  )

# expand dummies
expand_dummy <- function(x) {
  out <- rep(0, times = 3)
  out[as.numeric(x)] <- 1
  out
}

df_long |> 
  group_by(id, task) |> 
  reframe(choice = expand_dummy(choice))
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>    id                task  choice
#>    <chr>             <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 1          0
#>  2 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 1          1
#>  3 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 1          0
#>  4 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 2          1
#>  5 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 2          0
#>  6 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 2          0
#>  7 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 3          1
#>  8 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 3          0
#>  9 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 3          0
#> 10 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 4          0
#> 11 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 4          1
#> 12 R_88j7lG37gLfxk22 4          0
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>